# How to convert .fmt file to .txt file

Tags: r

I am doing computations with GAUSS/Aptech, and I just use 'save' syntax to save the results.

Then the results are saved in **.fmt** format.I guess there must be some GAUSS' syntax(or functions) which can export the results into .txt, but I cannot find that syntax(or function).

Is there any functionto read **.fmt** files in R?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time, but I came across this same problem, and found the following code from [APTECH forum](https://www.aptech.com/questions/convert-fmt-file-to-xls-or-txt-file/) which run perfectly.

Hope this helps anyone to come.

> Let's say that you have some data in a file called my_variable.fmt and
>   you want to save it if a file named my_xls_file.xls. You can
>   accomplish that like this:
>
> ```
> //load the matrix from the .fmt file
> load my_variable;
>
> //write it to an Excel file
> xlsWrite(my_variable, "my_xls_file", "A1", 1, "");
> ```
>
> To write the data to a .txt file you use the output function and the
>   print function like this:
>
> ```
> //load the matrix from the .fmt file
> load my_variable;
>
> //set output to print to 'my_txt_file.txt'
> //(reset means if the file exists write over it)
> output file=output.txt reset;
>
> //print 'my_variable' sending output to
> //the screen and 'my_txt_file.txt'
> print my_variable;
>
> //turn output to file off so no more
> //print statements go to this file
> output off;
> ```